# creating media player button from user control in main form c#

Tags: c#, forms, user-controls, axwindowsmediaplayer

I want to play media player in main form, from user control that media player is in there. How can C call media player with buttons that I put them in main form?

```
    private void player1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void bunifuImageButton7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code snippet seems to have nothing at all to do with the question

Comment: i dont know what to write in the play button that named bunifuImageButton7_Click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you have added a media player object to your form, and it's the COM object, `axWindowsMediaPlayer` (from your tags).  Let's assume it has the default name of `axWindowsMediaPlayer1`.

I am also assuming that your `bunifuImageButton7` is the Play button.

You need to load the path of your media file into the mediaplayer's URL property, and then activate its Play control, like this:

```
private void bunifuImageButton7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text;

axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

This was easily found on the Microsoft site.  You might want to visit their site and bookmark it, as it contains everything you need to know about the media player:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmp/axwindowsmediaplayer-object--vb-and-c

Documentation for all the other player controls is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmp/iwmpcontrols--vb-and-c